# zsh: command not found: UI5 vs code

Tags: macos, npm, visual-studio-code, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I just installed vs code on MacOs 10.

After installing npm and nodejs I expected that the ui5 command would work seamlessly, unfortunately it was not the case.

I get the following error when I execute the "ui5 serve" command:

```
mbm@Ms-MacBook-Pro ui5demo % ui5 serve
zsh: command not found: ui5
mbm@Ms-MacBook-Pro ui5demo %
```

Does anyone have an idea what step I missed here?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you install `@ui5/cli` as described in the doc? https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/GettingStarted/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by opening the terminal then execute:

```sh
sudo npm install --global @ui5/cli
```